# Raspberry Pi 4 - screen rotation

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, display

I just got my new Raspberry Pi 4 and I'm trying to rotate the screen. Usually on previous Raspberry versions I did that simply by putting *display_rotate=1* to config.txt, but when doing this on Raspberry 4 the screen is partly black and it's not rotated properly. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use screen configuration utility from preferences menu.